# Show module based on Referer URL

Tags: php, jquery, module-display

I have a site where I need to display a module based on the URL which the user has typed into their browser.

If the user types in thisdomain.co.uk they will be redirected to thenewdomain.co.uk/camps where I want a pop up/lightbox to be shown.

If they land directly on thenewdomain.co.uk/camps the pop up should not be shown.

Can this be done through jQuery or PHP and how can I load the module based on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it with Nonumber's **Advanced Module Manager** Pro version, as it allows adding custom PHP to determine if a module will be loaded or not:

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager/userguide#4_Assignment-options

In that PHP check, you'd use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`. You have an example that involves that variable here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948109/return-to-previous-page-in-joomla

More info about that variable here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php